# Is Prefix (Stackify) telling me my database call is open?

Tags: stackify

[image: Prefix trace]

I noticed the green line at the bottom started with a database call and is just staying there.  Does this means my db call is stuck open or something?

Answer (score 1):

No, this graph is Execution Time over Time and the green line is there due to the existence of some database calls within the period.  Its simply an artifact of the graphing itself.